# How to extract a tar while ignoring permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, command-line-interface, tar

I am transferring a tar file between two servers and extracting when it is received. The issue I am having is that the permissions are being retained and applied on the target server causing permission issues.

Is there a way to extract a tar file with ignoring the original permissions of the files it is extracting.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Network and administration tasks are also part of the development role in a lot of modern companies. Especially when it comes to integration and testing topics this kind of knowledge is often nesessary. I am a software engineer and I had the same question while configuring some Jenkins jobs. Maybe the devision between these categories is no longer wise.

Answer (score 3):

--no-same-permissions
seems to "and" the umask, so even less permissions then in the tar.

Comment: `umask -S` gives `u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx`, a file in the tar has 700 permissions, it gets extracted as `-rwx------`

Comment: [libarchive itself](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/blob/5bb998d869979140156bce59c0ff8f9063a25581/libarchive/archive_write_disk_posix.c#L2351) is hard coded with this behavior.

Comment: android adb `tar: Unknown option no-same-permission`

Answer (score 1):

The default options for tar command on CentOS-7.2 includes `--no-same-permissions`

The output from tar manual includes the following:

```
--no-same-permissions
 apply the user's umask when extracting permissions from the archive (default for ordinary users)
```